parseInt works in JavaScript, but not in C#
I'm trying to convert this JavaScript code to C#. It is a hexadecimal string that is the value of a crypto token.
Here is what works in JavaScript:
parseInt("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000056bc75e2d63100000", 16)

Here is what I have tried in C#:
var result = Int16.Parse("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000056bc75e2d63100000");

I get the error Input string was not in a correct format. What am I doing wrong?

lack of style argument - look up AllowHexSpecifier in documentation - of course, the number is a little larger than an Int16 ...

It's not working in JavaScript either. That value is too large to be safely represented as a JavaScript number. You might try BigInt.

@Pointy - it does work in javascript - though may not be correct of course (it is correct in this case)

@JaromandaX well yea, I figure if it's a crypto token being the correct number would be kind-of important

the number is too large. try to use var result = new System.ComponentModel.Int128Converter().ConvertFromString(x); BTW, 16 related to  base... not as int16..

@Pointy biginteger is smaller on 2 positions. 128 should be fine.

the number is too large for int.
void Main()
{
    string x = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000056bc75e2d63100000";
    new System.ComponentModel.Int128Converter().ConvertFromString(x).Dump();
}

result would be 100000000000000000000
